# Resolve path for stylesheets in HTML-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using `html-webpack-plugin` to generate `index.html` on the fly. It works perfectly fine. But, the problem is, I'm also using `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to extract the `css` out of `js`.

As given in the docs of `html-webpack-plugin`

> If you have any CSS assets in webpack's output (for example, CSS extracted with the ExtractTextPlugin) then these will be included with  tags in the HTML head.

It adds a `<link>` pointing to my css. But the link looks like this.

**Current output**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/../css/index.css" />
```

I need the url to be resolved like this

**Expected output**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/index.css" />
```

**My webpack config (essential parts only)**

```
output: {
        path: path.resolve('./build/app/js'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/js/',
    },
    plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin(path.normalize('../css/index.css')),
      new HTMLwebpackPlugin({
        filename: '../index.html',
        template: './app/views/index.ejs',
        hash: true,
      }),
]
```

The `build`'s folder structuer is like

```
|--js
|  |-main.js
|
--css
|  |-index.css
|
|--fonts
|
|--img
|
index.html
```

*All the output destinations for the plugins will be relative to the `path` given in the `output` config of webpack*

Answer (score 1):

the current output `/js/../css/index.css` is caused by the publicPath `/js/` and the extract url `../css/index.css`.

so, if you want to resolve it, just do:

1. change the publicPath into `/`.(I recommend that you shoud set the publicPath to your app dev root url).
2. change `new ExtractTextPlugin(path.normalize('../css/index.css'))` into `new ExtractTextPlugin(path.normalize('css/index.css'))`.
3. `HTMLwebpackPlugin` -> `filename` also should be changed

Comment: this will fix the css issue. but what about the js . that will be screwed up after this,

Comment: Yep! It's a solution.

Answer (score -1):

## Here is a full demo version!

[image]

## my `webpack.config.js`

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * @Created by xgqfrms on 2016/1/26.
 * @version 1.0.0 created
 * @description Using Next Generation Vanilla JS & JS Modules today with Webpack 3 & Babel!
 *
 * @license MIT
 * @copyright xgqfrms 2016-forever || 2018-present
 * @update 2018.1.29
 *
 */

// import { export } from "module-name";

/* "module": "webpack.config.mjs", ??? */
// import path from "path";
// import webpack from "webpack";
// import UglifyJSPlugin from "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin";
// import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";


const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack'); //to access built-in plugins
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');// template
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");// extract css files

// set process.env.NODE_ENV && npm run dev
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    console.log(', Looks like we are in development mode!');
}else{
    console.log('Tada, , we are in production mode!');
}

// const extractSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('stylesheets/[name]-one.scss');
const extractSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: (getPath) => {
        // relative path
        return getPath('css/[name].[hash:16].css');
        // js/../css & bug ???
        // return getPath('../css/[name].css');
        // return getPath('../css/[name].[hash:16].css').replace('js/../css', './css');
        // return getPath('/css/[name].[hash:16].css').replace('/css', '/css');
        // return getPath('../css/[name].css').replace('js/css', 'css');// relative path
    },
    // allChunks: true,
});
const extractSASS = new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].css');

const BASE_URI = {
    MODULES: './src/modules/',
    ES5: './src/es5/',
    APP: './src/index.js',
    NIM: './src/modules/no-import-module',
};



const MODULES_OBJ = [
    "module01",
    "module02",
    // "module03",
];

let entry_obj = {};
MODULES_OBJ.forEach(
    (item, i) => {
        entry_obj[item] = `${BASE_URI.MODULES}/${item}`;
    }
);

entry_obj["index"] = `${BASE_URI.APP}`;
entry_obj["no-import-module"] = `${BASE_URI.NIM}`;


module.exports = {
    entry: Object.assign({}, entry_obj),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/"),
        // path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/js/"),
        // filename: '[name].min.js',
        filename: 'js/[name].[hash:16].min.js',// hash version
        // [hash] & [chunkhash] can using [hash:16] (default 20)。
        // filename: "[chunkhash].bundle.js",
        // publicPath: '/'
        // pathinfo: true,
        // sourceMapFilename:  [name], [id], [hash] & [chunkhash], // default "[file].map"。
    },
    resolve: {
        // auto resolve files's extensions
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx','.scss', '.sass', '.css'],
    },
    module: {
        // loaders
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                // test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                // exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                // loader: "babel-loader",
                // options: {
                //     presets: ['env'],
                // },
                // use: 'babel-loader',
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            presets: ['env'],
                        },
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                // test: /\.scss$/,
                test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
                // test: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                url: false,
                                minimize: true,
                                sourceMap: true,
                                modules: true,
                                localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
                                // camelCase: true,
                                // importLoaders: 1,
                                // // 0 => none loader(default); 1 => postcss-loader; 2 => postcss-loader, sass-loader
                                // alias: {
                                //     "../fonts/bootstrap": "bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap"
                                // },
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                // includePaths: [
                                //     path.resolve("./node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets")
                                // ],
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    // allChunks: true,
                    publicPath: "./dist",
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000
                }
            },
        ],
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            extractComments: true,// {Boolean|RegExp|Function<(node, comment) -> {Boolean|Object}>}
            // test: /\.js$/i,// test: /\.js($&#124;\?)/i
            // include: /\/includes/,
            // exclude: /\/excludes/,
            // parallel: true,
            // parallel: {
            //     cache: true,
            //     workers: 2, // for e.g
            // },
            // uglifyOptions: {
            //     ie8: true,// ie8: false,
            //     ecma: 5,//ecma: 8,
            //     parse: {...options},
            //     mangle: {
            //         ...options,
            //         properties: {
            //             // mangle property options
            //         }
            //     },
            //     output: {
            //         comments: false,
            //         beautify: false,
            //         ...options
            //     },
            //     compress: {...options},
            //     warnings: false
            // },
            // warningsFilter: (src) => true
        }),
        extractSCSS,
        extractSASS,
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'using ES6 today with webpack3 & babel!',
            // filename: '../index.html',// relative path
            filename: './index.html',
            template: './src/index.html',
            // favicon: "",
            minify: {
                // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                html5: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeEmptyElements: true,
                quoteCharacter: true,
                // useShortDoctype: true,
                // removeTagWhitespace: true,
            },
            hash: true,// all files & path hash
        }),
        // new CleanWebpackPlugin(['build']),// rm-rf
    ],
};
```